# Why is a buffer used in Win32 API syscall cast to [1<<20]<type> array?

Tags: pointers, winapi, go

I'm writing a golang application which interacts with [Windows Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685141(v=vs.85).aspx)  using the [windows/svc](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc) package.

When I'm looking at the package source code how syscalls are being done I see interesting cast construct:

```
name := syscall.UTF16ToString((*[1 << 20]uint16)(unsafe.Pointer(s.ServiceName))[:]
```

Extracted from [mgr.go](https://github.com/golang/sys/blob/master/windows/svc/mgr/mgr.go)

This is a common patttern when dealing with Win32 API when one needs to pass a pre-allocated buffer to receive a value from Win32 API function, usually an array or a structure.

I understand that Win API returns a unicode string represented by its pointer and it is passed to the `syscall.UTF16ToString(s []uint16)` function to convert it to the go string in this case.

I'm confused from the part when an unsafe pointer is cast to the pointer to 1M array, `*[1<<20]uint16`.

Why the size if 1M [1<<20]?

Buffer for a value is allocated dynamically, not with fixed size of 1M.

Comment: @BenVoigt you are right, I meant 1 MB (1024 KB), not 1 KB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to choose a static size for the array type, so `1<<20` is chosen to be large enough to allow for any reasonable buffer returned by the call.

There is nothing special about this size, sometimes you'll see `1<<31-1` since it's the largest array for 32bit platforms, or `1<<30` since it looks nicer. It really doesn't matter as long as the type can contain the returned data.

Comment: Ok, so the point is, that you cast pointer to static array and then create slice of it. However the slice in the example has the same, big length, as array, so the underlying code has to know how to find the real length, in this case `syscall.UTF16ToString` searches for the zero and then re-slices slice to correct length. Right?

Comment: @vlasta: yes, when you use his pattern you have to treat the slice like you would an array in C and not count on the length. If the length is known at the time, you'll often see it the length and capacity set immediately so that it can be safely used as a regular slice.